# Flash SecurityError about sandbox. force to loadPolicyFile ,but it didn't work

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, sandbox, crossdomain.xml

i have a crossdomain.xml on my server. but it not in "/". and i use `loadPolicyFile` to load this crossdomain.xml.

```
Security.allowDomain("*")
Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
Security.loadPolicyFile(AddressContext.getCurrentEnv().split("rest")[0]+"crossdomain.xml")
```

the PolicyFile's url is like this : `http://siteA.com/aop/crossdomain.xml`.

and my restful webservices address is like this : `http://siteA.com/aop/rest/start`

crossdomain.xml include my flash's host url.

the weird thing is flash still tried to load the `http://siteA.com/crossdomain.xml` like this

[image: werid img]

first is right and response 200. the second response 400 .

finally, the flash still told me SecrityError#2048

i don't know why?

Comment: From what I know the flash always tries to load the crossdomain.xml from the domain root/. can\t you put it in there to fix the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Security.allowDomain("*")
Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
```

This is useless and it makes your SWF vulnerable.

Can you post the content of your crossdomain. What value did you set for the meta-policy tag?